# How to remove hyperlink border in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, hyperlink

Does anyone know how to remove the default dotted border of a hyperlink in css?

[image]

Also, how do I move the hyperlink to the left so it alligns with the password label? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just set the border color to `transparent` in a CSS stylesheet. The padding can be removed using the `-fx-padding` property:

```css
.hyperlink {
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-padding: 4 0 4 0;
}
```

or set the border to empty from java code

```
link.setBorder(Border.EMPTY);
link.setPadding(new Insets(4, 0, 4, 0));
```